# How the string prints the name without termination symbol ;(semicolon)?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
if(printf("Hello World")){

}
}
```

this is editted which i copied from the compiler ...
Try this its truly working and print as Hello World

Comment: how `Java` tag related here?

Comment: What language are you actually using? I doubt it's all 3...

Comment: I m sorry ... for including c++ and java

Comment: I have removed the java and C++ code. This is not Java or C++ code (although it can be compiled with a C++ compiler).

Comment: I doubt you tried the code you posted, as it will not even compile.

Comment: it worked try out it will print value in output screen

Comment: Negative marking is too bad for this question .Have u tried this in c program

Comment: There are at least two errors in that code that will make it not pass a compiler. If your compiler actually accepts this code it's not a C compiler.

Comment: Edited version still doesn't compile w/gcc and default options - what compiler are you using?

Comment: turboc compiler windows

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper perhaps its been long time you have not worked on `C`. Please revisit some basic c book. Suggesting you not to use turbo C compiler.

Comment: The code as it is now (4th revision) will most definitely compile, and there is nothing extraordinary about it either...

Answer (score 2):

You have to remember that a function call is an *expression*, and that in C you can have *any* expression as the condition for an `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the problem is here.

`printf()` is just a function. It returns a value (an `int` that says how many characters were printed).

So when used as the controlling expression in an `if`, of course it's called ("evaluated") since the `if` needs to know the return value.

Calling `printf()` has the usual side-effect of generating output.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried running this and got following Build messages

[image]

However, printf() returns the number of characters it has printed , Unless you put printf("") as condition, it will evaluate to be true. ;)

*printf("Hello World")* is an expression not statement, so you don't need semi-colon there.